# Parsing and Regular Expression for Condional Logic String

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, string-parsing

I have to tokenize a   conditional string expression :

> Aritmetic operators are  = +, -, *, /, %
>
> Boolean operators are =  &&, ||
>
> Conditional Operators are = ==, >=, >, <, <=, <,!=

An example expression is = (x+3>5*y)&&(z>=3 || k!=x)

What i want is tokenize this string = operators + operands.

Because of ">" and ">=" and "=" and "!=" [ which contains same string] i have problems with tokenizing.

**PS1**: I do not want to make complex lexial analysis. Just simply parse
if possible with reqular expressions.

**PS2:** Or in other words, i look for a regular expression which is given
sample expression wihout whitespace =

```
(x+3>5*y)&&(z>=3 || k!=x)
```

and will produce each token is separated with a white space like :

```
( x + 3 > 5 * y ) && ( z >= 3 || k != x )
```

Comment: "PS: I do not want to make complex lexial analysis. Just simply parse if possible with reqular expressions." - yes, but that presumes that what you are parsing is "regular" (which has a definition, etc). When it comes to processing complex expressions like this (the parenthesis in particular), personally I'd be using a simple tokenizer that tracks "what did we just read" (only yielding the token when it knows it has changed - so you don't yield `<` as a token until you've read the next character, so you know that it isn't `<=`), then a shunting yard algorithm to create an AST

Comment: I will use such an algorithm.No problem for evaluation. But first I have to tokenize this in a right way.Look for simple tokeizer which can tokenizer ">" , ">=" truely...

Comment: I've written several such tokenizers; they are indeed pretty simple - but none of them involve regex, for the reason that IMO this is not a problem that is ideally suited to regular expressions.

Comment: Well, Any simple tokenizer example which parse this string and give tokens as an array will be great. But be carefull i have an operators which has same characters like ">",">=" in which i have to check next characters etc which makes simple parser  "ugly"...

Comment: Here's some hacky Java code I just came up with which seems to solve your problem - `"(x+3>5*y)&&(z>=3 || k!=x)".replaceAll("==?|>=?|<=?|!=|&&|\\|\\||[-()+*/%]", " $0 ").replaceAll(" {2,}", " ").trim()`. I'm sure you can manage to convert that to C# if it is sufficient.

Comment: Dukeling...It can be hacky...But not even work for simple "3>=4" expression. And becarefull i hava ">" and ">=" oprators.

Comment: Do you need floating point literals? What about unary expressions (e.g. -5, -a, !myBool)? Boolean literals?

Comment: No just simple expression for now...

Comment: [It seems to work just fine here](https://ideone.com/d4HUKI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a regex, but a basic tokenizer that might just work (note that you don't need to do the `string.Join` - you can use the `IEnumerable<string>` via `foreach`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // and will produce each token is separated with a white space like : ( x + 3 > 5 * y ) && ( z >= 3 || k != x )
        string recombined = string.Join(" ", Tokenize("(x+3>5*y)&&(z>=3 || k!=x)"));
        // output: ( x + 3 > 5 * y ) && ( z >= 3 || k != x )
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string input)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                if (buffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return Flush(buffer);
                }
                continue; // just skip whitespace
            }

            if (IsOperatorChar(c))
            {
                if (buffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    // we have back-buffer; could be a>b, but could be >=
                    // need to check if there is a combined operator candidate
                    if (!CanCombine(buffer, c))
                    {
                        yield return Flush(buffer);
                    }
                }
                buffer.Append(c);
                continue;
            }

            // so here, the new character is *not* an operator; if we have
            // a back-buffer that *is* operators, yield that
            if (buffer.Length > 0 && IsOperatorChar(buffer[0]))
            {
                yield return Flush(buffer);
            }

            // append
            buffer.Append(c);
        }
        // out of chars... anything left?
        if (buffer.Length != 0)
            yield return Flush(buffer);
    }
    static string Flush(StringBuilder buffer)
    {
        string s = buffer.ToString();
        buffer.Clear();
        return s;
    }
    static readonly string[] operators = { "+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "=", "&&", "||", "==", ">=", ">", "<", "<=", "!=", "(",")" };
    static readonly char[] opChars = operators.SelectMany(x => x.ToCharArray()).Distinct().ToArray();

    static bool IsOperatorChar(char newChar)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(opChars, newChar) >= 0;
    }
    static bool CanCombine(StringBuilder buffer, char c)
    {
        foreach (var op in operators)
        {
            if (op.Length <= buffer.Length) continue;
            // check starts with same plus this one
            bool startsWith = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                if (op[i] != buffer[i])
                {
                    startsWith = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (startsWith && op[buffer.Length] == c) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.It works.For now just upvote the answer.Look for interesting reqular expression answer, although it may not be good candidate for reqular expression

Answer (score 1):

If you can predefine all the operators that you're going to use, something like this might work for you.

Be sure to put the double-character operators earlier in the regex, so that you will try to match '<' before you match '<='.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = "!=|<=|>=|\\|\\||\\&\\&|\\d+|[a-z()+\\-*/<>]";
      string sentence = "(x+35>5*y)&&(z>=3 || k!=x)";

      foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
         Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                           match.Value, match.Index);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Found '(' at position 0
Found 'x' at position 1
Found '+' at position 2
Found '35' at position 3
Found '>' at position 5
Found '5' at position 6
Found '*' at position 7
Found 'y' at position 8
Found ')' at position 9
Found '&&' at position 10
Found '(' at position 12
Found 'z' at position 13
Found '>=' at position 14
Found '3' at position 16
Found '||' at position 18
Found 'k' at position 21
Found '!=' at position 22
Found 'x' at position 24
Found ')' at position 25
```